# Full-text index in PostgreSQL (not 'english' or 'simple)?

Tags: postgresql

I need to store a few hundred thousand HTML documents in a database and be able to search them. But not just for content - I need the searches to match class names, script names and id values  (among other things) that might appear as attributes within the HTML tags in the documents. I tried using to_tsvector('english', tableColumn) and to_tsvector('simple', tableColumn) but neither seem to match the contents of attributes in tags. Specifically, I did this:

```
create index an_index on myTable using gin (to_tsvector('simple',tableColumn))
```

and then:

```
select url from myTable where to_tsvector ('simple', tableContent) @@ to_tsquery ('myscript.js')
```

I expected it to retrieve all documents that contained a reference to myscript.js. But it returns no results.

Is it possible to achieve the results I want using the full-text search?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you looked into myTable to see how the full text search indexes your data? How far from your expected 'myscript.js' are you? If the content is tokenized wrongly, you will need to tune the parser.

Answer (score 1):

Try instead.

```
SELECT url FROM myTable WHERE tableColumn @@ to_tsquery ('simple','myscript.js')
```

Comment: and failing that change to_tsquery to plainto_tsquery.